# IBM Worklight - Keep me logged in feature

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a mobile application using Worklight, in which when a user signs in after authentication he should not sign in again and again. Could you please tell me how to keep the user logged in?

Comment: Logging in establishes a session that will normally last for some time, typically you set an idle timeout for the session. For the duration of the session you should not need to log in again. So: are you seeing freuqent logins? If so explain to us what authentication you have set up.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Yes, i have to log in again and again. I am doing simple authentication using NonValidatingLoginModule.Could you please tell me where do we need to set the session.

Comment: Session should happen automatically, nothing special you need to do. You can up the idle timeout in worklight.properties, but default should be fine. You're going to have to explain a bit more about what you have done. Update your question with details about your security tests, what you're protecting with them, and the exact sequence under which you get the repeated login requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'Form based authentication in hybrid applications' project in the Getting Started page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_security

Answer (score 0):

There is also another feature of Worklight called 'heartbeat' which keeps your session alive by sending a simple request to the server. This also happens automagically without need configuration. It can be configured see here for more information (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Fc_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html&resultof%3D%2522%2568%2565%2561%2572%2574%2562%2565%2561%2574%2522%2520).

Can you give more context to your question so the community can help figure out the problem? What version of Worklight are you using?