# Worklight - How to achieve an "always logged-in" state in an application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

In the Facebook app for example, it is not required to login again and again every time the app is launched. Instead, there is a login screen once and after a successful login, next time it will not be displayed.

On a similar basis, I am developing an app in worklight which shows login screen always whenever I open the app.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve the same in worklight?

Comment: This isn't magic... You could implement it so that after the first time the user verifies the credentials against a remote backend, to store some token in the app storage and the next time you will check for the existence of this token, and if it exists you will display the app contents instead of the login screen... You need to think about and then implement it.

Comment: Can I use encrypted cache for it?

Comment: Better use JSONStore instead. It provides stronger encryption.

Comment: duplicated as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606122/ibm-worklight-keep-me-logged-in-feature

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate; the answers in that other questions didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

One rudimentary way to achieve a always-logged state could be by following the below:

After the first time the user credentials are verified against the remote backend, store a token in a secure manner for example by encrypting it in a JSONStore.

Each time the application is launched, first check for the existence of this token.

- If it's there, continue to the "secured area" of the application
- Otherwise, display a login form